# How to return the link from background url with simple dom html?

Tags: php, html, css, dom, web-crawler

I am trying to get the link of a background

```
<div class="mine" style="background: url('http://www.something.com/something.jpg')"></div>
```

I am using find('div.mine')

```
$link = find('div.mine');
```

$link returns the html code containing all the

How do I parse so it returns only the link?

Comment: Are you trying to parse CSS? If not, can you post the HTML markup too?

Comment: What do you get in output when `echo $link->background;` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I rephrased my question. I hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax isn't quite correct. You're doing `$link = find('div.mine');` but that should be `$link = $yourHTML->find('div.mine');` instead.

Get all the divs with the class name `mine` first, loop through them, and get the style attributes. Now you'll have a string like:

```
background: url('http://www.something.com/something.jpg')
```

You could then use a CSS Parser (recommended way), or a regular expression to grab just the URL part from that string.

```
if(preg_match('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $link, $matches)) {
    $image_url = $matches[0];
}
```

Full code:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.html');
$divs = $html->find('div.mine');
foreach ($divs as $div) { 
    $link = $div->style; 
}

if(preg_match('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $link, $matches)) {
    $image_url = $matches[0];
}
echo $image_url;
```

Output:

```
http://www.something.com/something.jpg
```

The URL matching regex pattern is from Wordpress' `make_clickable` function in `wp-includes/formatting.php`. See [this](http://forrst.com/posts/using_wordpress_function_make_clickable_to_con-Xbx) post for the complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

try with `substr()` function to extract the text